# Trouble with AutoFilter and defining range which results in expecting array error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to filter data with an `autofilter` based on user input. The user can check a box and the data should be filtered out. I am having trouble defining the range to use my `autofilter` though.

Here is the code that I am currently running:

```
dim WholeSheetRange as Range    
'turn on autofilter if not on
If Not ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
End If

Set WholeSheetRange = Range("A1:M" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))

If stn_DEN.Value = True Then
   WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=DEN"
ElseIf stn_EWR.Value = True Then
   WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=EWR"
ElseIf stn_IAD.Value = True Then
   WholeSheetRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=IAD"

End If
```

This is currently resulting in an error that an array is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function *LastRow()* in this line dows not exist:

```
Set WholeSheetRange = Range("A1:M" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
```

*(there may be other error)*

Comment: Thanks! I also realized my index was wrong. It needed to be 5 instead of 4.